# How do you prove the inequality $\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2} < 2$?

Tags: inequality

How do you prove:

$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2} < 2$$

I have some competitions in my country, so I have to prepare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing, for $N>1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{N^2}&<\frac{1}{1\times 2}+\frac{1}{2\times 3}+\frac{1}{3\times 4}+...+\frac{1}{N \times (N-1)}\\\\
&=(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+...+(\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N})\\\\
&=1-\frac{1}{N}
\end{align}
$$ then 
$$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{N^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{N}$$ giving the result.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2-k}$$
The Series in RHS is telescoping.

Comment: You might want to be more careful there... RHS is not defined for $k = 1$..

Comment: @ivo terek do you see $k=2$ ?

Comment: This comment is a year old now. He probably corrected the $k=1$ immediately after I pointed it.